# Estimate the volume of symmetric convex set in $\mathbb R^n$ in terms of the number of lattice points contained in the convex set.

Tags: reference-request, convex-geometry, integer-lattices

Suppose $K$ is a convex set in $\mathbb R^n$ which is symmetric with respect to the origin. [Minkowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_theorem) tells us that if the volume of $K$ is greater than $2^n$, then $K$ contains a nonzero integer point.

According to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/283988/123740) MO post, it is claimed that $ |\mathbb Z^n \cap K| \ge \frac{1}{2^n}\mathrm{vol}(K) $ and the bound is in general tight. Can someone provide some reference on this? Thank you!

Comment: I don't have a proof of the inequality, but to see it is attained: take $K$ to be the open cube of side length $2$ centered at the origin, which has volume $2^n$ but contains no other points in $\mathbb{Z}^n$. (This shows that the constant $1/2^n$ is optimal, but doesn't necessarily rule out tighter non-linear bounds as a function of $\text{vol}(K)$.)